# how i can start the gradient of image when push a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, gradient

i have a problem with gradient code, i code it in css and everything is work perfect but the problem is that the gradient of image is start automatically, so i want to make the gradient start when i press the button

i tried to connect it with function in  java script but it didn't work

```
<style>
.image {
width: 50vw;
height: 70vh;
position relative;
margin-top: -49%;
background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff, 
#d9d9d9, #b3b3b3, #8c8c8c, #595959, #333333, #000000 ,#000000 ,#000000);
background-size: 400% 400%;
-webkit-animation: Gradient 5s ;
-moz-animation: Gradient 5s ;
animation: Gradient 5s ;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
}
100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
}
}
</style>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="switch" value="on" onclick="changeImage()" />
<input type="radio" name="switch" value="off" checked="checked"         
onclick="changeImage()"/>

</div>


<div class = "image">
<img src="image/bef_logo.png" id="myImage" style= "width: 10vw; position: 
absolute; margin: 11% 0% 0% 19%;">
</div>

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        if (image.src.match("image/bef_logo.png")) {
            image.src = "image/aft_logo.png";
        }
        else {
            image.src = "image/bef_logo.png";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

this is my code , the image and gradient .. all i want is to start gradient (which is appear in css code .image) when function changeimage() is applied

Comment: please upload your images to internet and add the url here. not with local url !!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the animation independent of the image by creating a new class in CSS:

```
.switch-animation{
 -webkit-animation: Gradient 5s ;
-moz-animation: Gradient 5s ;
animation: Gradient 5s ;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Everything animation related is taken out and added to that class.

Once you have the class, add the line of code below somewhere in your `changeImage()` function, this will toggle the animation.

```
<script>
   function changeImage() {

    if (image.src.match("image/bef_logo.png")) {

        //Code to toggle animating class:
        document.querySelector('.image').classList.toggle('switch-animation');

        image.src = "image/aft_logo.png";

    }
    else {
        image.src = "image/bef_logo.png";
    }

   }
</script>
```